# control Linear analysis error due to RMS(IIR) filter?

Tags: control-system, matlab, simulink

my Objectif is to get a frequency response of the open loop system of plant which will allow me to design the controller transfer function. after including the RMS filter, the Analysis tool of Simulink shows this error:

> Simulink Control Design  1 Clear
>   02:22 PM Elapsed: 0.29 sec
>   In "frestimate(modelname,op,io,in)", the input signal "in" is a frest.Sinestream signal which has parameter values for "Frequency" and "SamplesPerPeriod" such that it inherently has multiple sample times. Using such an input signal requires that samples rates belonging to the Simulink signals where your linearization input and output points are located are either continuous or fixed in minor time step and the linearization I/O io(2) does not satisfy this requirement. Consider either changing the sample time of Simulink signal where io(2) is located to continuous sample time or using frest.createFixedTsSinestream utility to create a sinestream signal that has a single sample rate.
>   Component:Simulink Control Design | Category:Frequency Response Estimation error

what I understood is that I have to use only one sample frequency which I cannot since i need the RMS filter. how can I get my frequeny response

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: I want to get the frequency response of the plant(modeled electronic system with IIR filter) using the Analysis tool of simulink. from it I can use the k factor method to design my controller. actualy it is when i add my last block, the IIR filter that the error pop up

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: why I am getting this error when I run the linear analysis tool on simulink?